# Approaching the diagonal is Funky

Tags: calculus

Here is something really funky that popped up in my head as I was thinking about walking across my room, which is a rectangle. Let's assume that it has side lengths of a and b. Now, If I walk from one corner to the opposite corner by only walking along the side lengths, I end up going a+d. Now, if I walk like [this](https://snag.gy/3LQB9u.jpg), I still end up going a+d. Even if I walk like [this](https://snag.gy/pxVn62.jpg), I still end up going a+d. My calculus intuition tells me that we should have ended up with sqrt(a^2+d^2) or should at least be approaching it. What is going on?

Comment: See this problem: http://www.askamathematician.com/2011/01/q-%CF%80-4/

Comment: In short, the problem is that even though the path in some sense converges to the diagonal path, the lengths do not. The first issue is that you need a proper definition of 'length of a path'. This will involve a derivative. You need more conditions to get convergence of this derivative as well!

Comment: And [version on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4).

Comment: [Very related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1953696/if-calculus-is-just-based-on-minute-approximations-cant-it-be-wrong).

Comment: @user202729 : The drawings and cartoons in the first version are hilarious! :D

Comment: Can someone plz explain this in layman's terms? I only know derivatives, not integrals